# Solr Search Facets: How do i make them count products and NOT product varieties

Tags: solr

The shop i'm working on sells clothing. Each item of clothing come in multiple varieties. For example Shirt A might come in: Red Large, Red Medium, Blue Large, Blue Medium, White Large, and White Medium.

At first I had added each variety as a solr doc. So for the above product I added 6 solr docs, each with the same Product ID. I got solr to group the results by Product ID and everything worked perfectly.

However the facet counts were all variety counts and not product counts. So for example .. just limiting it to the one product above - (if that were the only product in the system say).. the facet counts would show:

Red (2)
Blue (2)
White (2)

Which was correct, there were 2 documents added for each color. But really what i want to see is this:

Red (1)
Blue (1)
White (1)

As there is only 1 product for each color.

So now i'm thinking in order to do that I need to make each solr document a product.

In that case i would add the product, and add the field "color" 3 times *one red, one blue, one white*, and add the field size 3 times as well.  But now solr doesn't really know what size goes with each color. Maybe I only have white in small.

What is the correct way to go about this to make the facet counts as they should be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I could do this using grouping (field collapsing) here

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters

specially these parameters added to the query

```
group=true
group.field=product_id"
group.limit=100
group.facet=true
group.ngroups=true
```

group.facet is the one that really make the facets work with the groups like i wanted them to.

Comment: I would like to review our case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928299/solr-faceting-considering-the-availability-of-product-at-attribute-combination-l Let us know if you can guide us on similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have 2 options.

**Option 1:**

Once you get the list of facet values (Red, Blue & White in the given example), then fire the original query again with each facet value as a filter.  For example, if the original query was `q=xyz&group.field=ProductID` then fire `q=xyz&group.field=ProductID&group.ngroups=true&fq=color:Red`. The `ngroups` value in the response will give you the required count for Red. Similarly, fire a separate query for Blue and White.

**Option 2:**

Create a separate field called `Product_Color` which includes both the ProductID and the color. For example, if a product has ID is `ABC123` and color is `Red`, then `Product_Color` will be `ABC123_Red`. Now, to get the facets for color, fire a separate query which groups by `Product_Color` instead of `ProductID` and you will get the required facets with the correct values. Remeber to set `group.truncate=true` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking into [Facet Pivot](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting), which would allow you to have single document, tree like facet with proper counts and filtering.