# Solr faceting considering the availability of product at attribute combination level for e-commerce merchandise like Garment

Tags: search, solr, facet, faceted-search

We are using Apache Solr for powering our search & faceting for the e-commerce website.

We have a faceting filter that works fine except for the product that has the multiple combination for the attributes (variant options) that turns out to be different SKU, for example, a T-Shirt that has multiple colors & size options.

Currently, we have a facet that filters by Color as well as by Size, however, it does not consider the availability of product on combination level due to the fact that it is not indexed.

We want to have facet filter considers availability status of attribute combination, i.e.

Suppose we have T-Shirt in two colors, Red & Blue. In three sizes, S, M, L.

```
Red, S 1
Red, M 2
Red, L 2
Blue, S 0
Blue, M 5
Blue, L 1
```

When the large size goes out of stock for the Blue color, we want to disable the facet for that combination. i.e. Blue, L which has one qty available, goes out of stock, we want to disable L as facet option for Size when Blue color is selected.

Here is how it is being indexed, for the product.

```
Color:[Red,Blue]
Size:[S,M,L]
```

The Color & Size are the attribute value, which has the possible options indexed for that field separated by comma and then we are applying a split by transformation.

What could be the best way to index it that would allow us to support faceting on attribute combination level considering it's availability.

Comment: Right now the availability is not indexed, as you explained. Do you plan to add it to the index or would this information be available through another system/web-service?

Comment: @cheffe Yes, we would like to index that. However, I am not sure what will be the structural change to current index schema that would support faceting as we need it. How would you recommend it? We are open to change a schema / index structure to support this. Note that we are currently indexing using DIH. And we are open with having another web service as well. Just need an idea!

Comment: @Krunal i had exactly same issue , i managed to solve this issue by indexing sum (qty of all combination) for every product which has attribute combinations.
so when one of the combination has a qty more than zero it would consider it as a available product.

Comment: @Mohammad can you please elaborated how you did it? May you can answer with some more details! So you index it for all combination, but then how do you use it for faceting?